# How to share only source with SVN in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I want to share the source code of my project through SVN, but I can only share the entire project. How can I share only the source and/or specific folders within the project?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the folders you don't want to put under SVN, and choose "Add to SVN ignore". Commit. The SVN will always ignore this folder.